# APACHE Hive get the last element in array

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a file structure like this and I only want to get the last element which is a country. I used -1 in hive but its not working. 1 gets me the first element but I can not use -1 to get the last.

```
1 1887-11-28 10:24:42   Sao Paulo, SP, Brazil
1 1887-11-28 10:30:45   Sao Paulo, SP, Brazil
1 1887-11-28 10:54:11   Sao Paulo, SP, Brazil
1 1887-11-28 11:13:29   Se, Sao Paulo, SP, BR, Brazil
1 1887-11-28 11:21:11   Sao Paulo, SP, Brazil
```

Answer (score 1):

refer the below link, use the below mentioned UDF..

https://github.com/klout/brickhouse/blob/master/src/main/java/brickhouse/udf/collect/ArrayIndexUDF.java

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
hive (default)> select "ABC/DEF/GHI";
ABC/DEF/GHI
hive (default)> select split("ABC/DEF/GHI","/");
["ABC","DEF","GHI"]
hive (default)> select split("ABC/DEF/GHI","/")[size(split("ABC/DEF/GHI","/")) - 1];
GHI
hive (default)>
```